# Can't save all HTML output with TinyMCE in Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, tinymce

With TinyMCE 4 I experiencing some issues with the form. I can save, some basic functions work (bold, underline, quote, hr etc). But e.g. fonts, text color, font sizes etc will not save in my Django project.

I have installed `django-tinymce`. What could be the issue here? Is there something I forgot to do? This is my init:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "textareas",
    theme: "modern",
    skin: 'lightgray',
    menubar: false,
    toolbar1: "undo redo | sizeselect | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent blockquote hr | formats fontselect fontsizeselect forecolor | emoticons charmap | link image preview code",
    font_formats: 'Andale Mono=andale mono,times;'+ 'Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;'+ 'Arial Black=arial black,avant garde;'+ 'Book Antiqua=book antiqua,palatino;'+ 'Courier New=courier new,courier;'+ 'Georgia=georgia,palatino;'+ 'Helvetica=helvetica;'+ 'Impact=impact,chicago;'+ 'Symbol=symbol;'+ 'Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;'+ 'Terminal=terminal,monaco;'+ 'Times New Roman=times new roman,times;'+ 'Trebuchet MS=trebuchet ms,geneva;'+ 'Verdana=verdana,geneva;'+ 'Webdings=webdings;'+ 'Wingdings=wingdings,zapf dingbats',
    max_width: 930,
    min_height: 300,
    min_width: 930,
    plugins: [
          "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
          "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code",
          "insertdatetime media image nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
          "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools"
    ],
    language: "{{ language }}",
    directionality: "{{ directionality }}",
    spellchecker_languages: "{{ spellchecker_languages }}",
    spellchecker_rpc_url: "{{ spellchecker_rpc_url }}",
    file_browser_callback: "mce_filebrowser",
});
```